# Check if string has unicode '\u25CF'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I want to detect a unicode and format it to next line. To make it look bulleted.
Here's the sample text that renders from the database.
I'm using AntD and ReactJS.

I'm thinking if I can use this `toString.replace()`

[image]

```
const renderColumn = (text, record, index, rowKey, cardKey) => {
 return (
   <Form.Item>
    {getFieldDecorator(`${rowKey}-${cardKey}-${index}`, {
      initialValue: text, // THIS IS WHERE THE TEXT RENDER
      rules: [
        {
          required: true,
          message: '*Please fill out this field!',
        },
      ], 
    }
   </Form.Item>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example I used `split()` and `join()` methods.
I hope this code works for you.

**Example:**

```js
var mssg = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML;
mssg = mssg.split('●').join("<br>&#x25CF;");
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = mssg;
```

```html
<div>
    &#x25CF; Lorem ipsum dolor &#x25CF; Sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit &#x25CF; Sapiente eum, ut quas accusantium quasi
</div>
```